# Which selector would I use in CSS to make a Buddypress users profile image round?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, buddypress

I am using the BuddyPress, woo-commerce and WC vendors plugins to build my latest WordPress project.

For each of my vendors I wanted their Buddypress profile pictures displayed on each of their products listed for sale so I added the following code to my functions.php file:

```
function change_wcvendors_cart_sold_by_meta_template( $meta_html, $product_id, $vendor_id ) {
    if( ! $vendor_id ) {
        return $meta_html;
    }

    if( ! class_exists( 'WCV_Vendors' ) || ! function_exists( 'bbp_get_user_profile_url' ) ) {
        return $meta_html;
    }

    $profile_url    = bbp_get_user_profile_url( $vendor_id );
    $profile_name   = WCV_Vendors::is_vendor( $vendor_id ) ? WCV_Vendors::get_vendor_sold_by( $vendor_id ) : bp_core_get_user_displayname( $vendor_id );
    $profile_image  = bp_core_fetch_avatar( 'html=false&item_id=' . $vendor_id );

    $meta_html  = '%1$s %2$s <a href="' . $profile_url . '" class="no-lightbox vendor-bp-link">
                        <img src="' . $profile_image . '" class="avatar user-' . $vendor_id . '-avatar avatar-50 photo" alt="Profile picture" width="45" height="45">
                        &nbsp; ' . $profile_name . '
                    </a>';
    return $meta_html;
}
```

...and it worked and is now showing the user's BP profile image next to their username, next to the "sold by" text, please see here:

https://prnt.sc/s9paz8

But I was just wondering if it was possible to also make the image round using CSS? I have tried using the following code in the custom CSS section to make the image circle but it did not work so I think I am using the wrong selector:

```
. $profile_image {
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

Could anybody advise what the correct selector would be to use for selecting the BP profile image, this is how it looks when I inspect element using google chrome:

https://prnt.sc/s9pf8u

https://prnt.sc/s9pgat

Thank you in advance,

Comment: You can't target a PHP variable like `. $profile_image` with CSS. You have to target a class in one of the elements.  Hassaan Ali's answer below should take care of it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the CSS property `border-radius` to make your images round. I've found this js fiddle for you take a look.

http://jsfiddle.net/2QyY3/2/

Edit: Here's the demo code from your question:

```
function change_wcvendors_cart_sold_by_meta_template( $meta_html, $product_id, $vendor_id ) {
    if( ! $vendor_id ) {
        return $meta_html;
    }

    if( ! class_exists( 'WCV_Vendors' ) || ! function_exists( 'bbp_get_user_profile_url' ) ) {
        return $meta_html;
    }

    $profile_url    = bbp_get_user_profile_url( $vendor_id );
    $profile_name   = WCV_Vendors::is_vendor( $vendor_id ) ? WCV_Vendors::get_vendor_sold_by( $vendor_id ) : bp_core_get_user_displayname( $vendor_id );
    $profile_image  = bp_core_fetch_avatar( 'html=false&item_id=' . $vendor_id );

    $meta_html  = '%1$s %2$s <a href="' . $profile_url . '" class="no-lightbox vendor-bp-link">
                        <img src="' . $profile_image . '" class="round-image avatar user-' . $vendor_id . '-avatar avatar-50 photo" alt="Profile picture" width="45" height="45">
                        &nbsp; ' . $profile_name . '
                    </a>';
    return $meta_html;
}
```

CSS:

```
.round-image{
 border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Hassaan Ali , thank you very much for this!! I replaced the class to `"round-image avatar user-'` in the PHP code and added the CSS you recommended and it worked well on the WC vendor pages, as here [link](https://prnt.sc/s9reea) but on the homepage the profile image is still square, pls see [link](https://prnt.sc/s9rhs7), even though I can see the image has `"round-image avatar user-'` when I inspect element. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: I see you're using elementor. On this widget enter the same css and you'll be good to go. If you want to include this only once then include this css in the header template

Comment: ahh thanks. Unfortunately I am only using the free version of elementor and I can only add the class ID, which I did to that element, but it still didn't work. I then added `!important` after the  `border-radius: 50%` in the custome and it worked, pls see [link](https://prnt.sc/s9s1b5). But  as I don't like using the `!important`, I was just wondering about the other solution you mentioned, did you mean I could add the CSS to the header.php file?

Comment: The elementor provides the option to develop your own template i can't remember correctly if it was in the free version or not. The Header template css is included in whole website so css like this should be in the header or footer. The !important will enforce it to be implemented.

Comment: @ Hassaan Ali , Ahh I see. Ok, I will look into this. Thanks again for all your help!!!

Comment: If you've found your answer then mark it as an Answer for others to see.